# not able to decode json in swift

Tags: json, swift

This is the http client and the response is correct when printing the string, but it is showing conversion error when trying to decode

```
 let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ (data, response, error) in
                
                // Check for Error
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error took place \(error)")
                    return
                }
            do{
                let imageData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ImageDataModel.self,
                                                         from: data!)
                print(imageData)
            }catch{
                print("conversion error")
            }
  
            
        }
```

This is the data model used to decode

```
struct ImageDataModel: Decodable,Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var created: Int
    var data:Array<ImageData>

    struct ImageData: Decodable,Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        var url: String
    }

    init(created: Int, data: [ImageData]) {
        self.created = created
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

The response is

```
{
    "created": 1670598580,
    "data": [
        {
            "url": "https://oaidalleapiprodscus.blob.core.windows.net/private/org-t0OU052mWtWLkmxpWHfSoME9/user-mgq3wJsAIptbbj1l0yI0YIS4/img-WafK921SOTYJSY0oub4e0z4f.png?st=2022-12-09T14%3A09%3A40Z&se=2022-12-09T16%3A09%3A40Z&sp=r&sv=2021-08-06&sr=b&rscd=inline&rsct=image/png&skoid=6aaadede-4fb3-4698-a8f6-684d7786b067&sktid=a48cca56-e6da-484e-a814-9c849652bcb3&skt=2022-12-09T01%3A07%3A28Z&ske=2022-12-10T01%3A07%3A28Z&sks=b&skv=2021-08-06&sig=McfqQuL5FZ%2B0Ow1qms3i3phdYMZjmxcoNcfr4/7/XPk%3D"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://oaidalleapiprodscus.blob.core.windows.net/private/org-t0OU052mWtWLkmxpWHfSoME9/user-mgq3wJsAIptbbj1l0yI0YIS4/img-FgLNjPkxOcKk0wOz5pGKYO5c.png?st=2022-12-09T14%3A09%3A40Z&se=2022-12-09T16%3A09%3A40Z&sp=r&sv=2021-08-06&sr=b&rscd=inline&rsct=image/png&skoid=6aaadede-4fb3-4698-a8f6-684d7786b067&sktid=a48cca56-e6da-484e-a814-9c849652bcb3&skt=2022-12-09T01%3A07%3A28Z&ske=2022-12-10T01%3A07%3A28Z&sks=b&skv=2021-08-06&sig=h72lRrBUed0HKHkS3QEHy2RzfM65xbwtlJMM1NGK9w0%3D"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://oaidalleapiprodscus.blob.core.windows.net/private/org-t0OU052mWtWLkmxpWHfSoME9/user-mgq3wJsAIptbbj1l0yI0YIS4/img-mV5jtC9UQatb3zoDVG8lQw4u.png?st=2022-12-09T14%3A09%3A40Z&se=2022-12-09T16%3A09%3A40Z&sp=r&sv=2021-08-06&sr=b&rscd=inline&rsct=image/png&skoid=6aaadede-4fb3-4698-a8f6-684d7786b067&sktid=a48cca56-e6da-484e-a814-9c849652bcb3&skt=2022-12-09T01%3A07%3A28Z&ske=2022-12-10T01%3A07%3A28Z&sks=b&skv=2021-08-06&sig=pYrewa9h/B0gzOp7NwfzYwjdVlG4%2BwkpJCXdzuEw9HY%3D"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://oaidalleapiprodscus.blob.core.windows.net/private/org-t0OU052mWtWLkmxpWHfSoME9/user-mgq3wJsAIptbbj1l0yI0YIS4/img-PjwW7ctrLEjFkIuctE71V2jj.png?st=2022-12-09T14%3A09%3A40Z&se=2022-12-09T16%3A09%3A40Z&sp=r&sv=2021-08-06&sr=b&rscd=inline&rsct=image/png&skoid=6aaadede-4fb3-4698-a8f6-684d7786b067&sktid=a48cca56-e6da-484e-a814-9c849652bcb3&skt=2022-12-09T01%3A07%3A28Z&ske=2022-12-10T01%3A07%3A28Z&sks=b&skv=2021-08-06&sig=Mznigp33qXj1f2yO1kUfxiwJOG2XiAfKpXdBQBavu8Q%3D"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://oaidalleapiprodscus.blob.core.windows.net/private/org-t0OU052mWtWLkmxpWHfSoME9/user-mgq3wJsAIptbbj1l0yI0YIS4/img-3vZsW3Tr82PELAH2QDnGz2im.png?st=2022-12-09T14%3A09%3A40Z&se=2022-12-09T16%3A09%3A40Z&sp=r&sv=2021-08-06&sr=b&rscd=inline&rsct=image/png&skoid=6aaadede-4fb3-4698-a8f6-684d7786b067&sktid=a48cca56-e6da-484e-a814-9c849652bcb3&skt=2022-12-09T01%3A07%3A28Z&ske=2022-12-10T01%3A07%3A28Z&sks=b&skv=2021-08-06&sig=cIwENFt/fWP12wLtr%2BNQks6OuCgB%2BZORsT6dxHbk7ys%3D"
        }
    ]
}
```

I was expecting to store the json received into the struct

Comment: Change `print("conversion error")` to `print("conversion error: \(error)")` so you know what the actual problem is. And please remove the SwiftUI tag. Your question isn't related to SwiftUI at all.

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear:

> No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil)

You declared an `id` property but there is no key `id` in the JSON.

Basically there are two options:

1. Declare `id` as constant. It makes no sense anyway to declare an unique identifier mutable

   ```
   let id = UUID()
   ```

   You will get a warning but it can be ignored.
2. Specify explicit `CodingKeys` omitting `id`

   ```
   struct ImageDataModel: Decodable, Identifiable {
       private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case created, data}

       let id = UUID()
       var created: Int
       var data: Array<ImageData>

       struct ImageData: Decodable, Identifiable {
           private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case url }

       ...
   ```

Side note: Never print just a meaningless literal string in a `catch` block. Print always at least the `error` instance

```
 } catch {
     print("conversion error", error)
 }
```

Comment: So if i make id as let, it wont consider when decoding right ?

Comment: Yes, but as I said you get always a warning.